# Error on setting DesiredCapabilities for SauceLabs execution

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, saucelabs

The following was configured based on config listed in https://saucelabs.com/platforms.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platform", "Windows 8.1");
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "firefox");
capabilities.setCapability("version", "33.0.");
capabilities.setCapability("name", "Bamboo Job");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://user:key@localhost:4445/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

The above code results in the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.openqa.selenium.Platform.Windows 8.1
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
at org.openqa.selenium.Platform.valueOf(Platform.java:30)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.setCapability(DesiredCapabilities.java:168)
at com.automation.tool.internal.InitiateBrowser.getBrowser(InitiateBrowser.java:17)
at com.automation.tool.Automation_Tool.(Automation_Tool.java:36)
at ui_automation.Login_Validation.setUp(Login_Validation.java:19)
```

But when I supply values in the Platform enum, then the whole suite passes. ex:- WINDOWS, WIN8_1
But it is not possible to mention version in Mac or Linux using this method.

Please let me know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the `platform` setting is not determined by Selenium but by Sauce Labs. They have a [whole page](https://saucelabs.com/platforms) dedicated to telling you exactly what to put there. You can select the platform, browser, browser version and it will tell you exactly what you need.

At any rate the `platform` string for Linux is the string `"Linux"`. For Macs you have multiple choices depending on the version of the OS you want. The ones I saw were:

```
"OS X 10.10"
"OS X 10.9"
"OS X 10.8"
"OS X 10.6"
```

Comment: This got me thorugh... capabilities.setCapability("platform", "WINDOWS");
  capabilities.setCapability("os", "Windows 8.1");

Comment: Also, try not to directly specify string name/value pairs for capabilities. These may vary between each implementation version. Try something like `caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.WINDOWS);` to ensure you are using only those capabilities supported by the selenium version being used.

Comment: @shri046 Do you have a source that recommends this, or did you just come up with your own rule? Two observations: a) What I've put in my answer is exactly how **Sauce Labs** recommends you access their service. b) As I recall, how platforms are named is solely determined by the remote service and not by the Selenium client. Sauce Labs could require that the Linux platform be named "Potato".

Comment: @Louis My personal preference, not a rule. The reason for the exception in the opening post is because he/she may be using a version of selenium webdriver that does not support those platforms. Way I see it SauceLabs list of selenium webdriver speficic capabilities is driven off of [Platform](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Platform.java). Same with standard [CapabilityType](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.java) constants.

Answer (score 0):

It is a "feature" of Selenium 2.44. See the [issue 8083](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8083). You should use Seleniun 2.43.1.